# How to use Hashset/set in Jmeter beanshell scripting

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

I have list of IDs in an ArrayList, Can anyone help me how to get the count of unique ID's from the list.

Assume the `ArrayList` may contains:

```
ADD5C9
AA6F39
AA3D0D
AA48C9
8B9D48
63A859
ADD5C9
ADA162
AD9AD5
8B9D48
```

[please find the code for the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4B9q.png)

Thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.

In Groovy it would be quite enough to call [`unique()` function](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#unique-java.util.Collection-) for the ArrayList and it will remove all the duplicates:

```
def array = ['ADD5C9', 
             'AA6F39',
             'AA3D0D',
             'AA48C9',
             '8B9D48',
             '63A859',
             'ADD5C9',
             'ADA162',
             'AD9AD5',
             '8B9D48']

def unique = array.unique()

unique.each { value -> log.info(value) }
```

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Answer (score 2):

Add all list elements to a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) to remove any duplicate values:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(theArrayList);
int numberOfUniques = set.size();
```

Comment: I'm using JMeter 5.2.1 and it doesn't understand <>. So I need to use:
Set set = new HashSet(theArrayList);

Answer (score 1):

### Java-8+ solution

Or, You can use [`Stream::distinct`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) like so :

```
long count = list.stream().distinct().count();
```